# Can I detect when my project is being loaded by OmniSharp?

Tags: msbuild, omnisharp

I have an `Exec` task in my `csproj` file which should only run when the project is being compiled "for real", that is, not when the project file is just being loaded by OmniSharp.

How can I detect when my `csproj` file is being loaded by Omnisharp? Is there a build property I can look for?

```
<Exec Command="..." Condition="'$(OMNISHARP)' == ''" />
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not run as well when VS is loading the project? much of the loading behaviour is the same. Do you specifically mean OmniSharp? What about Rider or VS for Mac?

Comment: Can you give a full example of a target, where it is hooked into the build etc.?